# I don't get the formula RIN = beta * RE

Tags: transistors, current

There is a formula in Malvino's book (page 210 of the 6th edition) which states that the input base resistance of a transistor is beta times the emitter resistance.

To quote: "When seen from the base side of the transistor, the emitter resistance RE appears to be 100 times larger."(assuming beta = 100).

I don't get how it arrives to this conclusion. It implies that base and emitter voltage are the same.
So no VBE.

Could someone please explain more?

P.S. I would provide a screenshot of the above but the book is in Greek and also in printed format. (Edited to include the relevant quote from the 8th edition.)

[image]

Comment: Base and emitter voltages can't be the same, so what implies they are? And could it have something to do with Ie  being roughly beta*Ib?

Comment: @Justme assuming IB = VB/RIN and IE = VE/RE it follows that VE*RIN = beta * RE * VB.
If RIN = beta * RE then VE = VB.

Comment: @kosgian90 When reading Malvino, be aware that their definition of a *stiff* divider is almost never used for such circuits as it presents too high of a load on input circuits driving it. In fact, their entire enterprise in that section, trying to tell you how to design a CE stage, is going to cause more grief (big picture stuff to unlearn) than good (big picture stuff you can keep.)

Comment: @jonk Which book should I use according to you? I always held Malvino in high esteem.

Comment: @kosgian90 Long story related to experiences in several classes of students learning from the 8th edition two years ago. I could write up a long laundry list of inexcusable lapses, just with the problem sets alone. Things that should have been caught by now. However, a good teacher using the book can repair much of that. I just consider it terrible for self-teaching, or being used in a class where the teacher isn't exceptionally good and on top of things as it proceeds. In the right hands, pretty much anything can be made to work okay, I suppose.

Comment: @kosgian90 In editing your question, did I correctly identify the part you are looking at?

Comment: @jonk yes you did.

Comment: @kosgian90 Have you already learned about and feel comfortable with the idea that a resistor divider can be replaced by its Thevenin equivalent that includes a new ideal voltage source with a Thevenin series resistance? (So, replacing two resistors and a voltage source with one new voltage source and one new resistor, thereby simplifying things a bit?) Are you comfortable with that?

Comment: @jonk Yes I am. At first I didn't get why the resistors are considered to be in parallel connection when calculating Rth. But if you SC the voltage source it appears like the two resistors are connected to the same nodes (ground and whatever you wanna call the other node) therefore in parallel. Did I say it right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136108/discussion-between-kosgian90-and-jonk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand it like this:
If you were to measure the base's input resistance, you would apply a certain base voltage and measure the base current. Then you would calculate the resistance `Rin=Ub/Ib`.
As an example I just assume arbitrary values: `Rin=1V/1mA=1000 Ohm`.

But as the base current in practice causes 100 times the amount of emitter current, the actual current through the resistor is 100 as high, too. So the resistance is actually `Re=1V/100mA = 10 Ohm = Rin/100`.

The point is that you only have a fraction of the actual current available to do the measurement.